# Detect number of display monitor

Tags: c#

I already tried Screen.AllScreen, SystemInformation.MonitorCount, and WMI but all of them failed.

My application runs as a windows service, hence no visual Form or UI. Both Screen.AllScreen and SystemInformation.MonitorCount returns 1 even when I have 2 monitors. If I run my application in console, it returns the correct count of display but my requirement is that my application to run as a windows service (no UI).

Thanks!

Comment: if it is a service.... why would it matter that it doesn't know how many monitors you have?

Comment: Well, its in the nature of my application requirement. I need to run a hardware check on the remote pc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found answer to my own question.
Still end up using WMI.

I was initially using Win32_DesktopMonitor giving a non-reliable answer.

Using this query:

```
"SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Service = 'monitor'"
```

WMI returns the correct monitor instance connected to my PC.

Comment: Outstanding! Thank you, I looked every where without luck until this, I tested it on Windows 7, 8, 8.1 and they all worked (all 64 bit).

Answer (score -2):

I went with Win32_PnPEntity because it represents the information for Plug and Play Devices in your Device Manager, which will show you when you have a monitors plugged in. The way the query works in "searcher" is more likely to be accurate than others since it uses the Like Operator. I do this because on 3 different computers the monitor entries in Device manager appeared differently. E.g. (Pnp-Monitor, Pnp Monitor (Standard), Generic Pnp Monitor).

```
private int CountMonitorsInstalled()
{
    try
    {
     ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "select * from Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Name LIKE '%PnP%Monitor%'");
     return searcher.Get().Count;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: This won't compile because if it throws before the return, there is no return statement.

Comment: Also, you should be able to delete your other answer yourself.

Comment: Adding return 0 in the catch statement will return 0 if it fails.

Comment: I did delete my other answer but I don't get why I have -2 when I tested this code on 3 pc's it worked. When I tested the marked answer it only worked on 1 out of 3 pc's